# What's the purpose of `on_rq` field in `task_struct`?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling

I am now reading the source code of `try_to_wake_up()` function of Linux Kernel. This function does a lot and includes this: `return p->on_rq == TASK_ON_RQ_QUEUED`.

So, what is the actually purpose of `on_rq` field in `task_struct`.

BTW, does there exist some manuals or reading materials to introduce all the fields in `task_struct`? I think a fully understanding of these fields will help to clarify the mechanism of Linux's process scheduling.

Comment: There are resources that document linux scheduling but from what I realize they are not up to date. `task_struct` changes and added to that, not all fields are related to scheduling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux support separate run-queue for each CPU in the system.
Task or task_struct could be in run-queue. Also task_struct 
could migrate beatween cpu's.
p->on_rq indicate that task_struct
is in a process of migrating between two run-queues.
if p->on_rq == TASK_ON_RQ_MIGRATING task is migrating and
other sheduler with this task cannot work it should busy wait.
After it set to TASK_ON_RQ_QUEUED.